# Unknown connection on my SSH

Tags: ssh, tcp

I'd like to understand something on my SSH server.
When I type

```
netstat -an | grep -i ':22'
```

It came out this :

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.1:22          192.168.0.3:49236       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.1:22          43.229.53.72:16866      ESTABLISHED
```

My local IP is actually 192.168.0.3 and my server is at 192.168.0.1
How can I interpret 43.229.53.72:16866 ? It appears to be a Chinese address.

```
who -a
```

Gives me

```
                        2015-09-09 02:05                62 id=si    term=0 sortie=0
           démarrage système 2015-09-09 02:05
           niveau d'exécution 2 2015-09-09 02:05                   dernier=S
                        2015-09-09 02:06              1890 id=l2    term=0 sortie=0
IDENTIFIANT   tty1         2015-09-09 02:06              2987 id=1
IDENTIFIANT   tty5         2015-09-09 02:06              2991 id=5
IDENTIFIANT   tty2         2015-09-09 02:06              2988 id=2
IDENTIFIANT   tty4         2015-09-09 02:06              2990 id=4
IDENTIFIANT   tty3         2015-09-09 02:06              2989 id=3
IDENTIFIANT   ttyAMA0      2015-09-09 02:06              2993 id=T0
IDENTIFIANT   tty6         2015-09-09 02:06              2992 id=6
pi       + pts/0        2015-09-12 19:17   .          4965 (192.168.0.3)
           pts/1        2015-09-12 18:59              3529 id=ts/1  term=0 sortie=0


cat /var/log/auth.log | grep '43.229.53.72'
```

It appears that 43.229.53.72 tried so much times to connect to my ssh

```
Sep  8 21:55:21 raspberrypi sshd[30282]: Failed password for root from 43.229.53.72 port 39483 ssh2
Sep  8 21:55:23 raspberrypi sshd[30282]: Failed password for root from 43.229.53.72 port 39483 ssh2
Sep  8 21:55:25 raspberrypi sshd[30282]: Failed password for root from 43.229.53.72 port 39483 ssh2
Sep  8 21:55:25 raspberrypi sshd[30282]: Received disconnect from 43.229.53.72: 11:  [preauth]
Sep  8 21:55:25 raspberrypi sshd[30282]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=43.229.53.72  user=root
```

For sure he tries to brute-force the access and he succeed.
How to kick&blacklist this address and how to prevent from this in the future ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ instead.

Answer (score 7):

First note, that *establishing* TCP connection doesn't mean that the *authentication* succeed.

On public IP, this is really frequent that bots are trying to connect and try some common passwords and known users. You don't have to worry about this, but you can mitigate this phenomenon by these things:

- Install and set up `fail2ban` as proposed in the other answer
- Disable password authentication -- bots don't try public keys or other methods
- Disable `root` login -- most of the bots are trying to connection only to `root` user
- Move your service to different port than 22 -- this is hiding but also mitigates the most of the connections
- Install "port-knocking" tool that will hide your service for unauthorized access -- for example `fwknop`

Comment: I have the same thing going on. Good to know "establishing TCP connection doesn't mean that the authentication succeed". The answer is important to me